# Graph Representation - Linked List of Linked Lists

Tags: c, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

I know that an adjacency list is a common data structure for representing a graph, using an array of linked lists. I am working on implementing an inverted index for a simple search engine in C, and was going to use an adjacency list. However, I have found that one disadvantage of using an adjacency list is that if you don't know how many words are going to be in the inverted index, you have to assume that there is an arbitrarily large amount of words in the index (array elements) in order to create the adjacency list. This could result in excess memory being used. It is not a huge issue but I was wondering if there is a better way to implement it.

I was thinking that one solution to this problem would be to create a linked list of linked lists to represent my inverted index instead. I haven't seen many examples of a linked list of linked lists graph representation so I am assuming that is not commonly used or a conventional representation. I would like to know whether it is appropriate to use a linked list of linked lists to represent a graph in general? Or is it better to stick to using an adjacency list? Any insights would be really appreciated.

Comment: Using array (or mash-map) at the upper level allow you to access the node of the graph in O(1) - if you using link-list isn't that made the access to adjacency list of specific node to O(v)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a trade-off to both approaches.

You can use an adjacency list without using extra memory, however, every insertion and deletion will cost O(|V|) time.

If you, for instance, double the length of your array when you add a vertex for the first time, it will only cost you O(|V|) time every time you double your vertice count. However, you will almost always be holding extra memory using this approach.

If you choose to represent a graph with a LinkedList of LinkedLists you indeed optimize memory, but at a large performance trade-off. Finding the neighbours of a given node goes from O(|E|) time, to O(|V||E|) time, which eliminates one of the biggest advantages of an adjacency list.

And if you would like to do a more advanced operation- like traversing the graph- the performance cost will be extremely inefficient. For every neighbour of a vertex you would have to re-traverse the node LinkedList in order to find the neighbouring vertex.